# Is it possible to make an item in a WinJS ListView control be 100% the width of the ListView?

Tags: html, css, listview, winjs

In WinJS I can define a ListView and a corresponding template like this:

```
<div id="template" data-win-control="WinJS.Binding.Template">
<div style="width:100px;height:100px;">
    <p data-win-bind="innerText: text"></p>
</div>
</div>
<div id="list" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ListView" 
     data-win-options="{itemDataSource : Data.list.dataSource, 
     itemTemplate: select('#template')}">
</div>
```

The div inside the template has to have a width and a height defined, otherwise it won't work. My question is: how do I make the template fill the entire width of the listview using only css. Setting width to `100%` only makes it fill the parent `.win-container` element, not the listview itself. Setting the width to `100vw` isn't optimal because of margins.

Comment: If you only want to see one item at a time in a ListView, maybe you want to try a FlipView instead? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211711.aspx

Comment: I agree...the point of a ListView is that it displays multiple items according to a layout, and the item template is rendered once for each item in the data source. A FlipView is the control that displays one items at a time from a data source and sounds like the piece you need here.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. I want to display multiple list items in the ListView by having each item take up 100% of the width of the listview, but only 100px height. Anyway, I figured out a solution to my problem: using a WinJS.UI.Repeater object. It is documented here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/bg182879.aspx#Repeater